# Guardar arreglo en base de datos PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un arreglo que envio por AJAX  a PHP para insertarlo en la base de datos, el arreglo me llega de la siguiente manera:

```
$datas = 
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => fecha
                        [value] => 2016-08-10
                    )

            )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => identity
                [value] => 11434058
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => company
                [value] => 1
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => cc
                [value] => 2
            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => value
                [value] => 6
            )

    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => qov
                [value] => 1
            )

    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => concept
                [value] => 3
            )

    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => land
                [value] => 1
            )

    )
```

)

Lo he intentado recorrer para poder guardarlo en la base de datos, los valores `[name]` son los nombres de los campos de la base de datos con sus respectivos valores `[value]`

```
$datas   = $request->getPost('datas');
foreach ($datas as $indices) {
  $indice[$i] = $indices;
  foreach ($indices as $identities) {
    $identity[$j] = $identities;
    $j++;
  }
  $this->saveAction($indice[$i], $i);
  $i++;
}

//No he podido obtener esos valores en esta función hago la inserción
public function saveAction($val, $i) {
  $fecha = $val[0]['name]['value'];

  $new->fecha = $fecha;

  if($new->save()){
    $this->jsonResponseSuccess(
                array(
                    'id' => $new->id), 201, 'Created'
                );
  }
}
```

Uso phalcon framework, no se si estoy haciendo algún proceso mal, espero sea entendible la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estas recorriendo bien el arreglo, es un arreglo de 3 dimensiones, por lo que te falta un nivel por recorrer, aunque no se para que usas `$i` si puedes recorrer todo el arreglo directamente con `foreach`, prueba lo siguiente para recorrer tu arreglo:

```
$aux = array(
                0 => array(0 => 
                           array('name' => 'fecha',
                                 'value' => '2016-08-10'
                                )
                          )
                );

foreach($aux as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $clave => $valor){
        foreach($valor as $columna => $celda){
            echo "clave ".$columna." valor ".$celda."<br/>";
        }

    }
}
```

**EDICIÓN EN BASE A LOS COMENTARIOS**

Si quieres obtener las key(clave) del ultimo arreglo ese valor esta en `$columna`, si quieres obtener el valor del arreglo accediendo por la clave podrías hacer `$valor["$columna"]`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, esta bien pero lo que quiero son los valores ya que al imprimir `$celda` me da `fecha 2016-08-10 identity 11434058 company 1 cc 2 value 5 qov 1 concept 3 land 1` y no se como guardar solo esos valores de acuerdo al name

Comment: No he usado phalcon, pero si quieres obtener las key(clave) del ultimo arreglo ese valor esta en `$columna`, si quieres obtener el valor del arreglo accediendo por la clave podrías hacer $valor["$columna"].

Comment: Si funciono muchas gracias :)

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido :).